# using unix commands like grep and sed for the perl array

Tags: perl, unix, sed, grep

How do I grep for certain patterns in a perl array and use sed command and save output as another array,like below one

```
my @modifiedfiles=`echo @files | grep  -E '(DataFiles|Pfgas|Startups)' | sed -e 's/.*something//g; s/#.*$//g;'`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't - it makes no sense :)

Perl has `grep` and `map` builtin:

```
my @filteredfiles = grep { /(DataFiles|Pfgas|Startups)/ } @files;
my @modifiedfiles = map { s/.*something//g; s/#.*$//g; $_ } @filteredfiles;
```

Also possible in one step:

```
my @modifiedfiles =
    map { s/.*something//g; s/#.*$//g; $_ }
    grep { /(DataFiles|Pfgas|Startups)/ } @files;
```

But Perls `grep` and `map` behave differently from the command line `grep` and `map`. See the documentation for details:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html

If you really want to do it anyway, it's possible with something like:

```
use IPC::Open2;

$pid = open2(\*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_IN,
    "grep  -E '(DataFiles|Pfgas|Startups)' | sed -e 's/.*something//g; s/#.*$//g;"
);

for my $file (@files) {
    print CHLD_OUT $file."\n";
    my $result_fn = <CHLD_IN>;
    chomp $result_fn;
    push @modifiedfiles, $result_fn;
}
```

No, you don't want to this :) It has lots of drawbacks and a high risk of failing. I assume the script will even start to block if `grep` filtered out a file.

Comment: This is a nice answer, with step by step recormendations and. links to documentation +1 :-)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the inplace capability `s/.*something//g for @filteredfiles`

Answer (score 3):

Please *don't*, just use buildin Perl functions:

```
@modifiedfiles = map({
  s/.*something//g;
  s/#.*$//g;
} grep({ 
  /DataFiles|Pfgas|Startups/
} @files));
```

Comment: Unmatched ) in regex; marked by, I am getting this error!